# Safari saves random files to Desktop in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, safari, desktop, mouse

Sometimes, when I leave Safari (6.0.5) and look at my desktop, I find random files on it. These are always in the form of a `*.textClipping` file, or in the case of images, the original filename and extension.

For example, yesterday when I signed up for Stack Exchange, I found a file named with some  hex and a `png` extension on my desktop. This was actually my Stack Exchange/Gravatar identicon.

This issue seems to have started when I got my Magic Mouse.  It reflects the behavior of dragging selections or images to the desktop, so I think that something to do with the mouse is probably the cause.

Is there any way to disable the dragging behavior in Safari?  Any ideas on why exactly it's being triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .textClipping files are text that you've dragged out of an app to a folder location (in this case, the Desktop).

You can increase the delay required to drag a clipping using the following command:

```
defaults write -g NSDragAndDropTextDelay -int 10000
```

<sup>`-g` applies to all apps. To only apply to Safari, replace `-g` with `com.apple.Safari`.

Default delay is `1000` milliseconds (1 second).</sup>

To completely disable the ability to drag clippings, set the value to negative.

```
defaults write -g NSDragAndDropTextDelay -int -100
```

Comment: To be clear, I wasn't actually dragging the images myself. I saw no indication that the file was being dragged.

Comment: In addition to this, I added a user style using Stylish (a Safari extension) with `-webkit-user-drag: none;` to prevent images/links from doing this. I can't really tell that these are working, because the issue is a bit sporadic, but they seem to fix it.